# What is the value of $\mathcal B(n)$ here?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $\mathcal B(n)$ denote the number of $n$-digit numbers such that the sum of any two consecutive digits (from the left) equals the immediate next digit. For example, a few such $3$-digit numbers are $123, 134, 257$ and $404$. Similarly, such  $4$-digit numbers include $1235$ and $9099$.

By hand, I have come up with the following:

$\mathcal B(3)=45$

$\mathcal B(4)=25$

What about $\mathcal B(5)$? What about $\mathcal B(6)$? What about $\mathcal B(n)$?

Comment: How did you get $B(3)=46$?

Comment: I have written it, by hand.

Comment: Let C(n) be the number of ways to do it with no zeroes. You should be able to express B(n) in terms of a sum over C(m) up to n.

Comment: $\mathcal B(n)=0$ for $n>8.$ Such numbers are determined by the first two digits.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews

Yes. That is a good observation.

Comment: I got 45, 25, 8, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, ..  for B(3), B(4), ...

Comment: If $d_1$ is the first digit and $d_2$ The second, you will get an appropriate $n$-digit number iff $d_1 F_{n-2}+d_2F_{n-1}\leq 9,$ where $F_k$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number (starting with $F_0=0, F_1=1$)

Comment: I got the same result as irchans; so few options that they are easy to enumerate. Thomas' solution is nice, though, maybe you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Yes. I have got the sequence: 45, 25, 8, 4, 1, 1.

Comment: @callculus42 Excuse me for changing it to the correct one 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d_1$ is the first digit and $d_2$ is the second, then the $n$th digit, for $n>1,$ is: $$d_{n}=d_1F_{n-2}+d_2F_{n-1},\tag 1$$ where $F_k$ are the Fibonacci numbers, $$F_0=0,F_1=1,F_2=1,F_3=2,F_4=3,F_5=5,F_6=8,F_7=13,\dots.$$

Of course, we need $d_1\in\{1,2,\dots,9\}$ and $d_2\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and finally $d_n\leq 9.$

So $\mathcal B(n)$ is equal to the number of pairs $d_1,d_2$ with $(1)$ less than or equal to $9.$

For $n=3,$ this is the set of pairs $(d_1,d_2)$ with $d_1+d_2\leq 9.$ This gives $\mathcal B(3)=9+8+7+6+\dots+1=45.$

For $n=4,$ this is the set of pairs $(d_1,d_2)$ with $d_1+2d_2\leq 9.$ This gives $\mathcal B(4)=5+4+4+3+3+2+2+1+1=25.$

If $n=5,$ this is the number of pairs with $2d_1+3d_2\leq 9.$ This gives $\mathcal B(5)=3+2+2+1=8.$

If $n=6,$ this is the pairs with $3d_1+5d_2\leq 9.$ This gives $\mathcal B(6)=2+1+1=4.$

If $n=7,$ this is the pairs with $5d_1+8d_2\leq 9.$ This gives $\mathcal B(7)=1.$

If $n=8,$ this is the pairs with $8d_1+13d_2\leq 9,$ which again gives $\mathcal B(8)=1.$

For $n>8,$ $F_{n-1},F_{n-2}>10,$ so there are no solutions.

---

There probably isn't a much better way than enumerating the pairs. I don't expect a clean formula for the general base, for example. In base $b,$ $\mathcal B_b(n)$ will monotonically decrease until it reaches $0.$ You'll always have $\mathcal B_b(3)=\frac{b(b-1)}{2}.$

The closest we can come to is something like:

$$\mathcal B_b(n)=\sum_{d=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{b-1}{F_{n-2}}\right\rfloor}\left(1+\left\lfloor \frac{b-1-F_{n-2}d}{F_{n-1}}\right\rfloor\right)$$

Comment: Appreciable. Thanks a lot.